# Rails app, installing Devise, rake db:migrate error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, dbmigrate

Trying to re-install Devise.  Rails 4 on Postgresql

I've followed the instructions from Devise (like adding devise gem/bundle install) and made the changes to my environments/application.rb/added my flash messages

Then ran

`rails generate devise User`

and got this...

```
invoke  active_record

    create    db/migrate/20130819025615_add_devise_to_users.rb
    insert    app/models/user.rb
    route  devise_for :users
```

but the problem is when I try and run `rake db:migrate`  I get this error

`==  AddDeviseToUsers: migrating ===============================================
-- change_table(:users)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD COLUMN "email" character varying(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in exec'`

So I understand that the error is telling me that no table 'users' exists, but Devise is supposed to create this, so my main question is... What is the easiest way to fix this?

Also, why didnt Devise create this?  Will this cause future problems?

Should I Create a Users table in postgres, and then run the command again in Devise and let it change necessary files and "devise-ify" it? (If it will even do that)

Thanks!

Comment: Try to run `rake db:create` first

Comment: could you paste the content of your db/migrate/20130819025615_add_devise_to_users.rb file?

Comment: I think the problem occurs in development.rb. I had the error too and i realized it's because i haven't save config.action_mailer.default_url_option ={:host=>'localhost'} and i have a user.yml which i generated earlier using railscast omniauth page. so there's redundancy and i have to overwrite but didn't saw the comment to overwrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Devise creates a User table. `rails generate devise User` simply generates a migration that associates Devise with the User table. In your case, the User table does not exist yet. Hence, the error. First, you should write a migration that creates the User table. For example:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
    end
  end
end
```

Then run `rake db:migrate`. Ensure the migration that creates the table is run *before* db/migrate/20130819025615_add_devise_to_users.rb by naming the file appropriately.

Comment: This actually did not solve my problem, but this is the best answer based on the information given. The best possible answer anyone likely could have given so for that reason I will accept it.  But for anybody in the future, the error was within multiple PG databases.  You should delete migrations and all related files until you can run `rake db:migrate` then, check your pg databases for duplicates, and then reinstall pg and anything related.

Comment: @ChristianFlores (I'm a beginner). I think I have the same issue as you.  How do I check my pg databases for duplicates?

Comment: nvm. got it to work. checked -- didn't have duplicates. reinstalled everything. good to go.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to feed a cat (I am animal friendly)

Method 1:
1. rails db create
2. rails db setup
It executes your earlier migrations code and created Users and other migrations.

Method 2:
- Create migrations using 'rails generate devise User'
- run 'rake db:migrate'
This will do a fine job as well.

But, migrations is the way, if you need to add additional fields in the Users table any ways.